# Angular 7 CLI programmatically

Tags: angular

What I am trying to success is to have server which start angular 7 app. One other example where that would be needed would be to make more complex generation, like to add more files right after angular generate.

```
const client = require('@angular/cli');
client.serve(__dirname);
client.generate('service', 'services/user');
```

This code obviously is not working as .serve or .generate is not a function and I search docs for programmatically solution and couldn't find any. Have anyone succeed that?

Comment: Why do you need it? Do you need to run the server from your script and not for a command line?

Comment: Usually you would build your angular app with `npm run build` or `ng build --prod` and then serve your bundle as static content from your server. You do not need to _start_ (unclear) your app.

Comment: I need to start only server and have both client and server running on development level. One other example would be to make more complex generation, like to add more files right after angular generate.

Comment: Why can't you write a batch file that runs all the commands that you need?

Comment: This is kinda ugly, in same way I could use something like: `require('child_process')` and execute those, but this is something that would be better to be in the way of `require('@angular/cli');`. In case that it's not possible and not planning to be possible, I guess i have to use ugly methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a node script, that can serve an angular application.

You can run this script in the directory like your angular app (node ../angular-cli.js):

**Serve**

```
const angular = require('@angular/cli');
const run = angular.default;

const options = {
    cliArgs: [
        'serve',
    ]
};
run(options)
    .then(function () {
        console.log('then', arguments);
    })
    .catch(function () {
        console.log('catch', arguments);
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log('finally', arguments);
    });
```

**Generate**

```
const angular = require('@angular/cli');
const run = angular.default;

const options = {
    cliArgs: [
        'generate',
        'module',
        'test',
        '--routing=true',
    ]
};
run(options)
    .then(function () {
        console.log('then', arguments);
    })
    .catch(function () {
        console.log('catch', arguments);
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log('finally', arguments);
    });
```

Comment: this looks to be the official one, is there any documentation about this on Angular side?

Comment: No, I haven't found any